# How to resolve "Failed to resolve module specifier" error in a npm package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, import

I have a npm package called "mynpmpackage" . I have a file called index.js that has this content:

```js
export default const Sum = (a , b) => {
return a + b
}
```

package.json :

```json
{
"name":"mynpmpackage",
"version":"1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "module": "index.js"
}
```

I published this package with `npm publish` and It published correctly .
I created another directory , and Installed my package with `npm install` .

Then , I made an `index.html` file :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
<script type="module" src="test.js"></script>
</html>
```

in test.js  :

```js
import Sum from "mynpmpackage"
alert(Sum(3,4))
```

but it gave this Error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "mynpmpackage". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```